# How to connect to REST web service with PUT HTTP method in python using proxy?

Tags: python, rest, proxy, urllib2, httplib

I have *'corporate internal tool'* where python 2.5.2 is embedded. This mean that I cant use any other version or programming language.
So, code is following for HTTPLIB:

```
  connection =  httplib.HTTPSConnection('IP:PORT')
  body_content = '<INPUT><Var1>DATA</Var1></INPUT>/r/n'
  headers = {Authorization':'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXX','Accept':'text/xml','Content-Length':'XX','Host':'host name','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate'}
  connection.request('PUT', '/path/method',body_content, headers)
  result = connection.getresponse()
```

For urllib2 code is following:

```
  body_content = '<INPUT><Var1>DATA</Var1></INPUT>\r\n'
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler)
  request = urllib2.Request('https://IP:PORT/path/method', data=body_content)
  request.headers={'Content-length': 'XX', 'Host': 'host', 'Accept': 'text/xml', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate'}
  request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
  url = opener.open(request)
```

Both of them are working fine in default python 2.5.2 installation.
If I try to use the same code in tool that I got, the following errors appear:

HTTPLIB:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'ssl'
```

URLLIB2:

```
urlopen error unknown url type: https
```

As I understood, SSL support is removed. By the way: I can write my own libraries and placing them to correct folders makes them work.
So, the question is: 
How using Proxy connect to web service? 
I found following example:
http://www.pha.com.au/kb/index.php/Python_-_Using_a_proxy_for_HTTP_requests

But it is not working in my case. Do you have some suggestion how this can be solved?
It looks that building a separate proxy module for performing the HTTPS query in python can solve this problem. So, what can be the connecting procedure in this case?

Comment: You should probably clarify that your question is something other than "How using Proxy connect to web service?".